# Efficient matrix square root of large symmetric positive semidefinite matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a large (150,000 x 150,000) symmetric positive semidefinite sample covariance matrix whose matrix square root I wish to compute efficiently in Python.

Is there any way to speed up the square root computation given that the matrix is symmetric psd? scipy.linalg.sqrtm is slow for my purpose.

Comment: You matrix is HUGE. It takes 168 GiB in RAM. Moreover, `scipy.linalg.sqrtm` requires some additional space. 4 times the size of the matrix for PSD matrices on my machine (complex matrices require an even bigger space). This means ~840 GiB of RAM! Do you have at least that on the target machine? Most computing machines does not (even many supercomputer nodes). If so, this means you will use the swap memory which is much much slower. Note that `scipy.linalg.sqrtm` is not very optimized but not so bad either. It is not design for such a case and focuses on numerical stability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your application, if it is enough to find `Bs @ Bs.T ~ B`, you can use Cholesky decomposition. If not you could get the square root based on eigenvalue decomposition.

```py
import numpy as np;
import scipy.linalg
A = np.random.randn(1500, 1500)
```

```py
%%time
Bs = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(B)
```

`Wall time: 4.4 s` - Our baseline

```py
%%time
Bs = scipy.linalg.cholesky(B)
```

`Wall time: 52 ms` Cholesky is much faster

```py
D, V = scipy.linalg.eigh(B)
Bs = (V * np.sqrt(D)) @ V.T
```

`Wall time: 1.62 s` more than twice faster (it explores symmetry)

###### Using pytorch

Pytorch have supports some linear algebra functions, and they vectorize accross multiple CPUs

```py
import torch.linalg
B_cpu = torch.tensor(B, device='cpu')
```

Square root using eigh (12 logic / 6 physical CPUs)

```py
%%time
D, V = torch.linalg.eigh(B_cpu)
Bs = (V * torch.sqrt(D)) @ V.T
```

`Wall time: 400 ms`

Or Cholesky decomposition

```
Bs = torch.linalg.cholesky(B_cpu)
```

`Wall time: 27 ms`

Comment: Since numpy 1.8 there's also `np.linalg.cholesky`.

Answer (score 0):

## Why a new answer?

The other answer suggests the Cholesky decomposition, which only works for positive **definite** matrices.  While that restriction is very appropriate for a sample covariance matrix, the question specified a positive **semidefinite** matrix, which would cause a `LinAlgError` in Scipy/Numpy.  `eig` and `eigh` will both work for positive semidefinite, but as the other answer shows, these are slow.  There is a semidefinite decomposition related to Cholesky, the [LDLt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition).  If D is diagonal, we could simply take the elementwise square root as in an eigendecomposition.  However, in practice `scipy` uses a fast algorithm that produces a block-diagonal D.

## Solution

Because the LDL algorithm yields D with at most 2x2 blocks, we can upgrade from `eigh` to `eigh_tridiagonal`, which is dramatically faster.  Moreover, D is guaranteed to have the same (semi) definiteness of the original matrix, guaranteeing nonnegative eigenvalues.

## Timing

Below code compares `eigh` to a combination `ldl`+`eigh_tridiagonal`

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import ldl, eigh, eigh_tridiagonal, cholesky
import time

ldl_time = 0
eig_time = 0
tri_time = 0
n_trials = 20
size = 400
for trial in range(n_trials):
    arr = np.random.normal(size=(size,size))
    arr = arr @ arr.T
    a = time.time()
    vals, vecs = eigh(arr)
    eig_time += time.time() - a
    a = time.time()
    l, d, p = ldl(arr)
    ldl_time += time.time() - a
    a = time.time()
    w, v = eigh_tridiagonal(np.diag(d), np.diag(d, 1))
    tri_time += time.time() - a
    a = time.time()
    L = cholesky(arr)
    chol_time += time.time() - a
print(f"LDL alone took {ldl_time:.3f} seconds")
print(f"    Additional factorization of D took {tri_time:.3f} seconds")
print(f"On the other hand, eigendecomposition took {eig_time:.3f} seconds")
```

```
LDL alone took 0.444 seconds
    Additional factorization of D took 0.041 seconds
On the other hand, eigendecomposition took 2.145 seconds
```

We can reconstruct the original matrix with:

```py
np.linalg.norm(l @ (v * w) @ v.T @ l.T - arr)
```

```
3.4043016350272527e-12
```